# How do I place canvas only on top of a center-aligned image and not on the entire page?

Tags: angularjs, canvas, fabricjs

Using angularjs in my application and making use of fabric.js for canvas functionality.

Here's my html code:

```
<div id="imageContainer" style=" width: 100%; height: 90vh; overflow: hidden">
      <img id="imageId" align="middle" ng-src="{{image}}" on-load="setCanvasOnLoad()"/>
</div>
<div id="canvas-section">
      <canvas id="drawingCanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```

My image is aligned in the middle of the page. However, the canvas is spread across the page. Here's how I create a canvas over the image:

```
 var deferred = $q.defer();
    $timeout(function () {

    var image = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("#reboxImage"))[0];
                var drawingCanvasObject = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("#drawingCanvas"))[0];
                var canvasContainer = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("#canvas-section"))[0];

                drawingCanvasObject.width = image.offsetWidth;
                drawingCanvasObject.height = image.offsetHeight;

                canvasContainer.top = image.getBoundingClientRect().top;
                canvasContainer.left = image.getBoundingClientRect().left;
                drawingCanvasObject.style.zIndex = 15;
                drawingCanvasObject.style.position = "absolute";
                if (drawingCanvasObject.width > 0 && drawingCanvasObject.height > 0) {
                    if (!MyService.getCanvas()) {
                        MyService.setCanvas(new fabric.Canvas('drawingCanvas', {selection: false}));
                    }
                }

    return deferred.promise;
```

The CSS for #canvas-section is as follows:

```
#canvas-section{
    z-index: 10;  /* <- higher than your canvases if it needs to go on top */
    position: absolute;
   left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

How can we ensure that the canvas's width, height, position, left, top etc are aligned with the image always and equal to it?

Image attached: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your 'canvas-section' element inside an 'imageContainer' element and add to 'imageContainer' the style 'position: relative'. In this case you will have your canvas positionned absolute but relative to the image container.

**UPDATE:**

Try to rearrange your code like this:

```css
.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  }

.centered-wrapper {
  height: 230px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  }

.content-covering-image {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="centered-wrapper">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRQZHFAgf3rw0Eg_Mdx3PaGUYd4-9BB1fr503Tg0wjbivpFDTthSw"/>
  
  <span class="content-covering-image">canvas</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course use the class names that will fit your purpose and style.

Comment: I did that, did not help. :(

Comment: One thing is that you're setting the top and left property of the canvasContainer, but it does not have position absolute, the drawingCanvasObject has, so set the left and top to the drawingCanvasObject instead. Also please let us know what exactly is not working right now? Everything? Or just the left and top positioning?

Comment: I am unable to change the left and top positioning even when I set the left and top to the drawingCanvasObject

Comment: Right, because you're missing the style property. You need to use element.style.top

Comment: Doesn't help either.

Comment: Can you, please, describe or send an example of what you see right now?

Comment: Added an image explaining details.